# Disable Common Name Validation - Go HTTP Client

Tags: http, ssl, go

How do I disable common name validation inside of a go http client. I am doing mutual TLS with a common CA and hence common name validation means nothing.

The tls [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) say,

```
// ServerName is used to verify the hostname on the returned
// certificates unless InsecureSkipVerify is given. It is also included
// in the client's handshake to support virtual hosting unless it is
// an IP address.
ServerName string
```

I don't want to do `InsecureSkipVerify` but I don't want to validate the common name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would pass a `tls.Config` struct with your own `VerifyPeerCertificate` function, and then you would check the certificate yourself.

`VerifyPeerCertificate func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error`

> If normal verification fails then the handshake will abort before
>   considering this callback. If normal verification is disabled by
>   setting InsecureSkipVerify then this callback will be considered but
>   the verifiedChains argument will always be nil.

You can look [here](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#example_Certificate_Verify) for an example of how to verify a certificate.  Iif you look [here](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#VerifyOptions), you'll see that part of even this verification process includes checking the hostname, but luckily you'll see that it [skips it](https://golang.org/src/crypto/x509/verify.go?s=8414:8499#L298) if it's set to the empty string.

So, basically you write your own `VerifyPeerCertificate` function, convert the `rawCerts [][]byte`, which I think would look something like:

```
customVerify := func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
    roots := x509.NewCertPool()
    for _, rawCert := range rawCerts {
        cert, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCert)
        roots.AddCert(cert)
    }
    opts := x509.VerifyOptions{
        Roots:   roots,
    }
    _, err := cert.Verify(opts)
    return err
}

conf := tls.Config{
    //...
    VerifyPeerCertificate: customVerify,
}
```

Comment: is not performing common name validation normal? Or is my use case an edge case

Comment: IMO it doesn't really make sense to validate a cert but not the common name.  At that point I can pass you any domains valid certificate and you'll check and and say "Yup, looks ok", so you don't get any actual security.

Comment: where is the `cert` coming from in `_, err := cert.Verify(opts)`

Comment: @dave https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21971 implies the rawCerts ,apart from the first one, should be added as intermediate certs as tls.Config has a roots Pool already and I don't think the root certs would be in the rawCerts slice. (also `cert` would not be defined where you attempt to `Verify` it.) Then only the first rawCert is `Verify`-ed. As for a use case - consider a cluster of services you have deployed: the client can be configured with the same CA cert that signed the server cert so we can be sure to trust the server without needing n*SAN's

Answer (score 2):

Normal https post like this

```
pool := x509.NewCertPool()
caStr, err := ioutil.ReadFile(serverCAFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("read server ca file fail")
}
pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caStr)
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:    pool,
    },
}

client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
client.Post(url, bodyType, body)
```

But if your url is use ip(ex. https://127.0.0.1:8080/api/test) or you URL is not match certificate common name, and you want to only ignore certificate common name check, should do like this

```
pool := x509.NewCertPool()
caStr, err := ioutil.ReadFile(serverCAFile)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("read server ca file fail")
}
block, _ := pem.Decode(caStr)
if block == nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Decode ca file fail")
}
if block.Type != "CERTIFICATE" || len(block.Headers) != 0 {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Decode ca block file fail")
}

cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("ParseCertificate ca block file fail")
}

pool.AddCert(cert)

tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:    pool,
        ServerName: cert.Subject.CommonName,  //manual set ServerName
    },
}

client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
client.Post(url, bodyType, body)
```

Comment: this is dead on correct. THANK YOU!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more, I keep getting error `tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead`